# Convert hyperlink

Tags: python, html, markdown

I am trying to write a python function and convert markdown format link like: [text] (link), into < a href > tags in HTML. For example:

link(line)

```
link("Here is the link [Social Science Illustrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Science_Illustrated) I gave you yesterday.")

"Here is the link <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Science_Illustrated">Social Science Illustrated</a> I gave you yesterday."
```

And my code for now is:

```
def link(line):
  import re
  urls = re.compile(r"((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)")
  line = urls.sub(r'<a href="\1"></a>', line)
  return line
```

Output:

```
=> 'Here is the link [Social Science Illustrated] ( <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Science_Illustrated"></a> ) I gave you yesterday.'
```

So I was wondering how to convert [text] part into correct position?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to convert based on the `[text](link)` syntax:

```
def link(line):
  import re
  urls = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]*)]\(([^\)]*)\)')
  line = urls.sub(r'<a href="\2">\1</a>', line)
  return line
```

You don't have to validate the link. Any decent browser will not render it as a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import compile, sub

def html_archor_tag(match_obj):
    return '<a href="%(link)s">%(text)s</a>' %{'text': match_obj.group(1), 'link': match_obj.group(2)}

def link(line):
    markdown_url_re = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]*)]\(([^\)]*)\)')
    result = sub(markdown_url_re, html_archor_tag, line)
    return line
```

For more information on [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)